# Prevent screen change when I press tab which is already selected

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a CustomTabBarController with 4 tabs. When I am inside the 3rd tab, let's say I have a screen called A and I have a button which takes me a second screen called B. So, when I am on screen B and I am pressing the 3rd tab, I want to stay on screen B. The current app behaviour is when I am on screen B and I am pressing the 3rd tab, the app navigates to screen A.

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Post relevant code (as text). What you describe is not standard functionality of a tab bar controller.

Comment: @HangarRash clawesome's answer is the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `CustomTabBarController` subclass inherit the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol and in your `viewDidLoad()` set your controller's delegate to `self`.  Then override the `func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool` method returning `false` if the current `selectedViewController` equals the passed in view controller.

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.delegate = self
    }
    
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if selectedViewController == viewController {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    
}
```